# How to implement an "if an error occurs"-condition in Mathematica programming?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, data, error-tracking

In general Mathematica may return a value even if `NDSolve` has run into error.

A simple example is

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == Sin[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]
Print[First[y[1] /. s]]
```

which returns a value for `y[1]` along with an error

> > NDSolve::nderr: Error test failure at x == 4.8320299102694283008304019926655375368705512022963654026223787904735038`60.*^-7; unable to continue.

Now suppose that Mathematica is asked to loop over $10^4$ values of `y[0]` to find $10^4$ `y[1]` via `NDSolve` and then append  `{y[0], y[1]}` to some `.txt` file.

There are some different ways to achieve this but in any case one is facing the following question: from all the `y[1]`'s that are in my `.txt` in the end of the day (or in the next morning) which can I trust?

A brute-force approach is to open whatever `.nb` file you used, check the warnings one by one and then manually delete the corresponding values from the `.txt` file.

Another brute-force approach is not to loop over `NDSolve` at all and repeat manually the calculations for all $10^4$ `y[0]`'s

However it would be better if one had some variable e.g. `error` initiated as `error=0` at the beggining of each loop and then coined unity i.e. `error=1` when a warning occurs. If this value is then appended to the `.txt` along with `y[0]` and `y[1]` then one can erase any untrustworthy value with simple list manipulation.

In this case the above simplistic example should look like

```
error=0; 
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == Sin[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]
Print[First[y[1] /. s]]
If[(...),{error=1}];
```

So the question is: what should be the condition in `(...)`? How can one implement the condition "if an arror occurs" in Mathematica programming?

Comment: Have you looked at the function `Check`?

Comment: I tried `Check[s =   NDSolve[{y'[x] == Sin[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 10], err]` which shows no error. However `Check` does not set `err` to unity. So probably I'd rather ask how to implement `Check` to `NDSolve`?

Comment: The basic syntax is `Check[expr, failexpr]` where `failexpr` is **evaluated** and returned if an error has occurred. In your case you could try `Check[s = ..., error=1]` if you want to use `If`. However I do not recommend this practice. You should perhaps have a look at `Throw` and `Catch`.

Comment: There are several standard practices, a couple of which are mentioned in the comments above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
ode1 = {y'[x] == Sin[x], y[0] == 0};
ode2 = {y'[x] == x, y[0] == 0};
ode3 = {y'[x] == Cos[x], y[0] == 0};
odes = {ode1, ode2, ode3}
Do[
 Print["solving ode number ", n];
 
 s = Quiet@Check[
    NDSolve[odes[[n]], y, {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]
    ,
    Null,
    NDSolve::nderr (*you can add more error code here*)
                    (*Or do not use this field at all to catch any error*)
    ];
 
 If[s === Null,
  Print["Skipping n=", n, " because error was detected"]
  ,
  Print["good n=", n];
  Print[First[y[1] /. s]] (*change this to write to file *)
  ]
 , {n, 1, Length@odes}]
```

[image]

So basically, you write to the file, only when `s` is not `Null`, which means no error messages were generated.

You can customize this as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your time Nasser! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any bibliography on how to loop over `NDSolve`? I really had no idea.

Comment: You could make one big list of all your odes? and just iterate over them as above. You could arrange them in an association also. One field for the ode, second field for the initial conditions, third field for the dependent variable, and so on. Then once the list is made, just run the Do loop over them.

Comment: Check out [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)